# XAMPP Index of localhost does NOT list all my projects but they are accessible when entering their address, for example: localhost/myapp/www

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

Before I reinstalled XAMPP I had like 5 projects in my htdocs folder and only 2 of them were showing up. Reinstall did not help. I do not know the reason. Projects are accessible when typing their address, but let´s say I had 50 projects, I really don't want to remember all of their addresses... So I want to find a fix for this issue while it´s just a small problem. Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Comment: If you have index.php or index.html in your htdocs folder then it will automatically open that page in your Browser. Why don't you just create a shortcut on your desktop to open your htdocs folder?

Comment: @StackSlave I guess I probably explained my problem poorly (maybe it´s because of my english, since it´s my second language). What you recommend is sort of a workaround in my eyes. I want to be able to see all my projects listed in the 'Index of /' - that´s the title of the page. Normally when you enter localhost, you get redirected to localhost/dashboard, which I deleted because i wanted to see the list of my projects. The problem is that not all of them show up. I hope I explained my problem a little better. I am new to Stack overflow so if I need to edit my question just let me know thanks.